# Is it possible to add report feature with a created team project in TFS?

Tags: tfs

It's clear if you use Team Explorer in Visual Studio 2017 to create your new team project, the reports folder will be created and the default reports added.

However, my classmate used web interface instead to create a new team project, which does not create the reports folder for that new team project.

I didn't find a way to add report for that existing project after go through everywhere in web portal. Is it possible to do this?

I'm using TFS2017

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [**TFSConfig**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/command-line/tfsconfig-cmd?view=azure-devops-2019) command line to handle this.

To add the reports folder use the following steps.

- Log onto your TFS server
- Open a command prompt as an administrator
- Navigate to the C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server
  1x.0\Tools directory Enter the following command, entering the
  appropriate values for each parameter.

  `TFSConfig addprojectreports /collection:”http://yourtfsserver:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection” /teamproject:”Patrick” /template:”Agile”`

This command will create a report site and folder. It will report its progress and output to the screen and a log file as it goes. Hope this helps.